# System Diagnostics Process Start for Android

Tags: android, mobile

I need to upload images to a server and when i click on the photo it should go to the location of the photo in the gallery. I want to be able to use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start on android system, is there any way I can get it to work?

example code ;

```
    localPath = myfile.Path;
    AndroidContentOpenerWrapper.OpenContent("file://" + localpath);;
```

Comment: There is nothing in the Android SDK called "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start". Is this from some specific framework, like Xamarin? If so, you might want to update your tags to reflect this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.